# Number of extensions of a character in an abelian group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, characters

**Question:** Let $A$ be an abelian finite group and $B$ a subgroup of $A$. Let $\phi$ be an irreducible character of $B$. Show there is an irreducible character $\Phi$ of $A$ such that $\Phi|_B=\phi$. The number of possible $\Phi$ is $[A:B]$.

I was able to prove the existence of the irreducible character $\Phi$ but I don't know how to prove that the number of possible $\Phi$ is $[A:B]$. Any help on that part is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me give you some hints and I let you fill out the details yourself. Look at the set $Irr(A/B)=\{\mu \in Irr(A): B \subseteq ker(\mu) \}$, the irreducible characters of $A/B$ basically. If $\phi \in Irr(B)$ and $\lambda$ is an extension, then for every $\mu \in Irr(A/B)$, $\lambda\mu$ is also an extension of $\phi$. Observe that $\#Irr(A/B)=|A:B|$. If $\mu$ runs over $Irr(A/B)$, then all the $\lambda\mu$ are different, since linear characters never take the value $0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I am now going to take a rest and soon I will try to fill out the details. As soon as I do this, I will accept the answer. Again, thank you for your help!

Comment: You are welcome, let me know if you need further explanation.

Comment: I hope you realised that in fact *every* extension $\psi$ of $\phi$ must be of the form $\lambda\mu$ with $\mu \in Irr(A/B)$: if $\mathscr{I}=\{\psi \in Irr(A): \psi_B=\phi\}$, then, $\phi^A=\sum_{\psi \in \mathscr{I}} \psi$ (all with multiplicity $1$ (use Frobenius Reciprocity!)). Hence $(\phi^A)_B=\#\mathscr{I} \cdot \phi$. Comparing degrees, it follows that $|A:B|=\#\mathscr{I}$, hence $\mathscr{I}=\{\lambda\mu: \mu \in Irr(A/B)\}$.